# How to compute 2D convolution using 1D convolution over rows and columns?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, convolution, gaussian

I'm looking for a method to compute the same result that `conv2` will give, by using `conv` in MATLAB. (I'm doing the convolution in C code and I need to compare the result between MATLAB and my code.)

I have heard that it's possible to use 1D convolutional vector multiplication to achieve the same result as 2D convolutional matrix multiplication, only if the kernel `K` is separable e.g gaussian kernel. Also, by doing this way, 1D-way is much faster than computing the 2D way.

Here I have collected some Matlab code:

```
% Create data
A = randn(10, 10);

% Create gaussian kernel
sigma = 1;
kernel_size = round(6 * sigma);

% Create mesh grid
[x, y] = meshgrid(-kernel_size:kernel_size, -kernel_size:kernel_size);

% Create gaussian 2D kernel
K = 1/(2*pi*sigma^2)*exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2)/(2*sigma^2));
```

I wonder how I can achieve the same result as `conv2(A, K, 'same')` if I'm using `conv` only. Should I first do `conv(A(i, :); K(i, :), 'same')` for each row and then `conv(A(:, i); K(:, i), 'same')` for each column?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes I know, but if I want to use conv ? (I'm doing conv in C code and I need to compare the result between Matlab and my code)

Comment: @LuisMendo yes. But conv is only for vectors

Comment: @LuisMendo Your edit is OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the 2-D kernel `K` is separable into a row vector `kr` and a column vector `kc` such that `K = kc*kr`, the result of `conv2(A, K, 'same')` can be obtained more efficiently as `conv2(kr, kc, A, 'same')` (or equivalently as `conv2(kc, kr, A, 'same')`).

If you need to use only `conv`, you have to convolve each row of `A` with `kr`,  and then each column of the result with `kc` (or equivalently in the opposite order).

So, in your example:

```
A = randn(10, 10);
sigma = 1;
kernel_size = round(6 * sigma);
[x, y] = meshgrid(-kernel_size:kernel_size, -kernel_size:kernel_size);
K = 1/(2*pi*sigma^2)*exp(-(x.^2 + y.^2)/(2*sigma^2));

result = conv2(A, K, 'same');
```

you can obtain the same result with

```
x = -kernel_size:kernel_size;
y = x.';
kr = 1/sqrt(2*pi)/sigma * exp(-x.^2/(2*sigma^2));
kc = 1/sqrt(2*pi)/sigma * exp(-y.^2/(2*sigma^2));

result_sep = NaN(size(A));
for r = 1:size(A,1)
    result_sep(r,:) = conv(A(r,:), kr, 'same');
end
for c = 1:size(A,1)
    result_sep(:,c) = conv(result_sep(:,c), kc, 'same');
end
```

Check:

```
max(max(abs(result-result_sep)))
```

gives a value of the order of [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), so the two results are the same up to floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: I till try that in C-code and compare with `conv2` I made in C as well. See which one is faster. Giving you a reply later.

Comment: Does this only work for `same`?

Comment: I haven't tried. Your question was for `'same'`

Comment: I have tried `conv` vs `conv2` in Pure C code. With `conv2` FFT 2D, it took me 0.2 seconds for a very large matrix. It took me 1.02 seconds with direct `conv` with separable kernel and it took med 20 seconds with direct `conv2`. So I guess FFT 1D for `conv` might be very useful here. Anyway, thank you.